# How to set email alert from test manager or from Team Foundation Server for MTM suite or plan?

Tags: c#, msdn, mtm, tms

I have read it on few msdn forum that test Management service in Team Foundation Server raises notifications on some specific actions by its users. You can subscribe

to these notifications to understand what’s going on in the server. Here are some of the important notifications which are raised by test management service.

TestRunStartedNotification TestRunChangedNotification TestRunCompletedNotification TestPlanChangedNotification TestSuiteChangedNotification TestConfigurationChangedNotification

Can anybody share the step for it like how to set alert for this after TestRunCompletedNotification mail should be sent to user. Can it be done through MTM. I know TFS alert but i want to it for specific suite or plan that email should be sent after test run over.

Or how to set email when test cases run completed for specific suite.

Is there any in built feature in mtm or tfs for email alert??

please help

Answer (score 0):

There is no default way to set alert/Notification email from MTM like TFS alert. You need to use TFS API to create a listener to listen to test events and implement sending e-mail yourself.

Check the events you can handle:

http://nkdagility.com/tfs-event-handler-for-team-foundation-server-2010/

And you need an event handler to use them:

http://nkdagility.com/tfs-event-handler-in-net-3-5-part-2-handling-team-foundation-server-events/

http://www.almguide.com/2011/12/tfs-server-side-event-handlers/